# AngularJS directive to directive communication throwing an error about controller not found

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

I have 2 directives, one for searching and one for pagination.  The pagination directive needs to access the search directive to find out what property we're currently searching by.  When I load the page though, it throws an error saying `Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'search', required by directive 'pagination', can't be found!`.  However I have a controller setup in my search directive.

Here is my search directive:

```
angular.module('webappApp')
  .directive('search', function ($route) {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'views/search.html',
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        searchOptions: '=',
        action: '=',
        currentProperty: '=',
        currentValue: '='
      },
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.searchBy = $scope.searchOptions[0].text;
        $scope.searchByProperty = $scope.searchOptions[0].property;

        $scope.setSearchBy = function(event, property, text) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $scope.searchBy = text;
          $scope.searchByProperty = property;
        };

        $scope.search = function() {
          $scope.searching = true;
          $scope.currentProperty = $scope.searchByProperty;
          $scope.currentValue = angular.element('#searchCriteria').val();
          $scope.action($scope.searchByProperty, $scope.currentValue, function() {
            $scope.searching = false;
          });
        };

        $scope.reload = function() {
          $route.reload();
        };
      }
    };
  });
```

Here is my pagination directive:

```
angular.module('webappApp')
  .directive('pagination', function () {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'views/pagination.html',
      restrict: 'E',
      require: '^search',
      scope: {
        basePath: '@',
        page: '=',
        sort: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, searchCtrl) {
        console.debug(searchCtrl);
        scope.searchByProperty = searchCtrl.searchByProperty;
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: Is `search` a parent of `pagination` as declared in the DOM?

Comment: No, they're siblings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for one directive to use another's controller by use of `require`, it needs to either share the same element as the controller containing directive, or it has to be a child of it.

You can't use `require` in the way you have, where the elements are siblings.

[Angular docs about directives, including require](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

If it doesn't make sense to rearrange the DOM in the way I've described, you should inject a service into both directives which contains the data/methods you wish to share between the two.

**Note**: you could also experiment with the $$nextSibling / $$prevSibling properties of the directives' scopes, but this would present only a very fragile solution

Comment: It took a bit of refactoring, but I decided the injected service approach was a bit cleaner because it didn't require me to add search related attributes to every DOM element that needed information about what was being searched for.  By injecting the new search service into my search directive, I was able to reduce the amount of scope attributes on the directive to simply "action" which references a function of the parent controller.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `require` in directive like that, however , since the only thing you need to pass between directives is a string , just bind them to the same property in parent controller (it can be parent directive controller):

```
...
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='MyCtrl as ctrl'> 
   <my-dir-one s1='ctrl.message'></my-dir-one>
   <my-dir-two s2='ctrl.message'></my-dir-two>
```

and first directives:

```
app.directive('myDirOne', function ($route) {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'views/my-dir-one.html',
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      s1: '=',
```

second directive

```
app.directive('myDirTwo', function ($route) {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'views/my-dir-one.html',
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      s2: '=',
```

Comment: This is a good solution for simple strings and I did try this successfully, but I felt like I was adding too many search related attributes to the pagination directive.  So I went with the injected service approach that @Marc-Kline suggested.  Thanks for your suggestion though :)